# How does the performance of a warped pan compare to a level one when using gas?

Tags: pan, stainless-steel, skillet, carbon-steel

Of course there will be hot spots when using it on anything besides gas because it won't sit flat.  But are there any performance disadvantages when using a slightly warped pan and gas? As far as I can tell even a brand new pan will still pool oil depending on how level your stove / floor is.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly warped pan will perform the same as a flat pan on gas from an efficiency perspective, the shape isn't going to waste energy. As for whether the warp will impact your cooking experience it's hard to say, a warp can cause coatings to flake off, or make liquids pool in or run away from particular spots.